# strange c++ template method specialisation issue

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I've come across a strange problem with method specialisation.

Given this code...

```
#include <string>

class X
{
public:

    template< typename T >
    void set( T v );
};

template<>
void X::set( const std::string & v )
{
}

template<>
void X::set( int v )
{
}

int main( int, char *[] )
{
    X x;

    std::string y;

    x.set( y );

    x.set( 1 );
}
```

When I link it with g++ 4.3.3 I get an undefined reference to 
`void X::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)`.

Which is basically an undefined reference to void `X::set( std::string )`.

So my question is, why doesn't the compiler use the specialisation with `const std::string &` ?

If I explicitly call `x.set< const std::string & >( y )` then this compiles and links fine.

Comment: In such scenario, you can also think of overloading rather than specialization. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=overload+vs+specialization

Comment: I realise (and it's been pointed out below) that I could have not used templates when creating the templated member function set(). However, I wanted to make sure that only the code that was used actaully gets compiled and I didn't want to have to provide a set() method if the code doesn't actually use it. i.e.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)
will explain the situation.

You might expect the specialization
`void X::set( const std::string& )` will participate in overload
resolution.
However, surprisingly,
specializations don't participate in overload resolution.

In the call `x.set( y )`, the compiler deduces the type of `T` in the primary
template from the argument `y` with a type `std::string`.
So, the compiler deduces that `T` is `std::string`, then searches matching
specialization.

However, since `std::string` and `const std::string&` are different types,
the compiler selects primary template in the end.

After proper primary template is selected, the matching specialization is
selected in the same manner as the case for class template.
The reason that the specialization `set( const std::string& )` isn't selected
is similar to that the specialization `A< std::string >` isn't selected
in the following code:

```
template< class > class A; // primary

template<> class A< const std::string& > {}; // specialization

int main() {
  A< std::string > a; // This doesn't select the specialization
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reverting back to original proposition after compilation:

Your method signature for string should not be a reference. Should be:

```
template<>
void X::set( const std::string v )
{
}
```

This is because in your template definition you have specified `T paramater` and not `T& paramater`

Comment: so I should supply an additional set declaration which has T & and then specialise the reference one?

Comment: Or you could typedef string& and use that.

Comment: I tried adding a "template< typename T > void X::set( T & v );" but got compilation errors suggesting ambiguity.

Comment: The compiler can't choose between pass by reference and pass by value. They are equally good matches.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not getting an ambiguity, I'm getting a link error, i.e. the compiler hasn't chosen at all.

Comment: @Adrian: Sorry, it's not supposed to work. At all. Functions can't be specialized. There is obviously a bug in gcc in that it fails to diagnose the problem and silently compiles the code wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's altogether incorrect syntax. When specializing templates, you have to include the angle brackets with the types you are specializing for. E.g.:

```
template<typename T>
struct X { ... };

template<>
struct X<int> { ... };
//      ^^^^^ see, there have to be angle brackets after the identifier
```

So

```
template<>
void X::set(std::string &) { ... }
```

is not specializing anything, it is implementing

```
class X {
    template<>
    void set(std::string &) { ... }
};
```

which is altogether different function. What I don't understand is why gcc didn't produce an error because the class does not have that member.

Now even if you used the supposedly-correct syntax, it wouldn't be correct, because, as already answered by Tom, you **can't specialize functions** (just overload with non-template version). In C++03, that is; it is allowed in C++0x.

Comment: Hmm.. yes, I also agree that the specialisation code was incorrect and am also surprised that gcc didn't complain about it. I'm a little perplexed by your statement though that you can't specialise functions as I plainly can by prodiding a specialisation based on "std::string" rather than "const std::string &" and it compiles and links correctly.

Comment: The compiler will do it as long as you don't tell it to be super-strict about the standard. But, it's still not technically "correct", so you may want to avoid such things for the sake of portability across compilers.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to use is overloading.

```
class X
{
public:
    void set( int v); //the case for ints
    void set( const std::string&) //the case for strings

    //The default catch all case.
    template< typename T >
    void set( T v );
};

//not a template specialisation.
void X::set( int v )
{
}
//not a template specialisation.
void X::set( const std::string & v )
{
}
//the catch all case 
template<typename T>
void X::set(T v)
{
}
```

The non-template operators will be chosen ahead of the template because they provide a better match if available.  Otherwise the template will be chosen

Comment: Yes, agreed but it doesn't really answer my question as to why the compiler didn't consider the const std::string & specialisation to be a good enough match.. or maybe I missed something

Comment: ... or any other function for that matter.

Comment: Hi Tom, but what if I wanted to provide declaration of a method but would like the user to supply it's implementation without having to derive from my class and use overloading. Surely I just declare the set as a template member function and then let the user write the specialisations dependent on what types the user requires.  I'm really beginning to doubt my approach though if it's hitting edge cases in the language..

Comment: ScaryAardvark, perhaps you can go into more detail about what you're trying to accomplish? We might be able to provide some alternate suggestions.

Comment: @ScaryAardvark: I believe in that case you want to create a class (`struct`, so you don't need the `public` keyword) template with the function as a method. User can specialize that. You can than wrap it in simple function template for type inference.